# Proof that the limit of $\frac{1}{x}$ as $x$ approaches $0$ does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

Hello I was hoping that someone might be able to verify that the following proof that $\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over x}$ does not exist is correct.

First assume that $\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over x} = L$. This means that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ if $0 < \lvert x\rvert < \delta$ then $\lvert{1\over x} - L \rvert <\epsilon.$  Now let $\epsilon=1$ and choose $x < \min(1,\delta)$.  Therefore there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $0 < \lvert x\rvert < \delta$ then $\lvert{1\over x} - L \rvert <\epsilon$.  It follows that $\lvert{1\over x}\rvert < 1+ \lvert L\rvert$.  However clearly $\lvert{1\over x}\rvert>1$ and therefore a contradiction has been reached and there is no number $L$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over x} = L$.

Comment: He is taking the limit of a function.

Comment: After the statement of the definition, which is well done, things break down. Yes, we can let $\epsilon=1$. Then by We need to show that there is an $x$ such that $|x|\lt \delta$ and $1/x$ is "far" from $L$. So the "bad" $x$ will depend on $L$, which yours doesn't.  Note that $|1/x|\gt 1 $ and $|1/x|\lt 1+L$ do not contradict each other.

Comment: Technically, picking $x=\min(1,\delta)$ does let you use the definition of limit, because it doesn't assure that $|x|<\delta$ if  $x=\delta$. That's a small nit compared to the problems noted in Theophile's answer.

Comment: Hint for a way to fix your answer: If you want $\left|\frac{1}{x}\right|\geq|L|+1$, what does that condition mean for $|x|$?

Answer (score 4):

You could argue with the equivalent definition of sequences:

Assume it exists a $L \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}= L$ then for any sequence $a_n \to 0 $ with $a_n \neq 0$ it follows $\frac{1}{a_n} \to L$.

Now take $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$, then $\frac{1}{a_n} = n \not \to L$ for any $L\in \mathbb{R}$, since the sequence is unbounded (any convergent sequence is bounded).

Answer (score 2):

> First assume that $\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over x} = L$. This means that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ if $0 < \lvert x\rvert < \delta$ then $\lvert{1\over x} - L \rvert <\epsilon.$

So far, so good.

> Now let $\epsilon=1$ and choose $x = \min(1,\delta)$.

Fine, although for which $\delta$? One way to write this would be to say, "$\ldots$ for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta_\epsilon > 0$ $\ldots$", so that you can then choose $x = \min(1,\delta_1)$.

> Therefore there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $0 < \lvert x\rvert < \delta$ then $\lvert{1\over x} - L \rvert <\epsilon$.

This is confusing: it's not clear why you write "therefore", because we already know this from assuming the limit exists (see the first line, above). Furthermore, in the second line, you have set a value for $\epsilon$ and seem to have implicitly chosen a specific $\delta$, but now you're moving back into generality.

> It follows that $\lvert{1\over x}\rvert < 1+ \lvert L\rvert$.

How does that follow?

> However clearly $\lvert{1\over x}\rvert>1$ and therefore a contradiction has been reached and there is no number $L$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0} {1\over x} = L$.

Where is the contradiction?

Comment: If ∣1/x−L∣<1 then it is also true that ∣1/x∣-∣L∣<1 so ∣1/x∣<∣L∣+1 however I had chosen x so that x<d and x<1 so that 1/x>1.  And from the previous statement ∣1/x∣<∣L∣+1 but this can not be true as 1/x>1.  I apologize for the lack of consistency in the proof as I am only learning how to write them properly.

Comment: @HenryKaragory Okay, the line "It follows that $\ldots$" works; it would just be good to explain it, as you did in your comment here. The last line, however, still has a problem, since there is no contradiction. You have shown that $1 < |1/x| < 1+|L|$, which isn't a problem.

Comment: I see now!  Thank you very much for the help, I have since read the proof that Spivak gives in his book Calculus.

Comment: @HenryKaragory You're welcome! Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\delta>0$, and $l$ any real number.

$$|x|<\delta \implies \left | \frac{1}{x} \right |=|f(x)|>\frac{1}{\delta}$$

$$\frac{1}{\delta}-|l|<|f(x)|-|l|\leq |f(x)-l|\tag{1}$$

Where I used the fact that $|x|-|y| \leq |x-y|$, $\forall x,y$.

Now choose any $\epsilon>0$ and consider the equation

$$\frac{1}{\delta}-|l|>\epsilon$$
$$\implies \delta<\frac{1}{|l|+\epsilon}\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can always find a $\delta$ such that

$$|f(x)-l|>\frac{1}{\delta}-|l|>\epsilon$$

Therefore, what we have shown is that

$\forall \epsilon>0$, there always exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta \implies |f(x)-l|>\epsilon$.

Therefore, $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}=l$ is false for all $l \in \mathbb{R}$